# How to remove border around global navigation

Tags: sharepoint-online, design, global-navigation

[image]

Recently, a border has appeared around certain navigation items. How do I remove this?

Comment: If you dont have any custom code running in your SharePoint Tenant, it is probably a Microsoft issue. Take it further with the Support or wait for a fix, they are certainly on it already if it affects all customers.

Comment: Will do, the global navigation and theme is not custom. I'll try support and see if they have anything to add.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may have noticed that the headings with the boxes don't have the Simple Link filled out in the term set and the ones without the boxes do.  That's how we resolved it on our environment.  I understand environments may differ.

Comment: While this does work it's not a great experience to have something selectable that really shouldn't be.

Answer (score 1):

Is it a custom navigation?

It only happens on some of nodes.

You need to use the F12 developer tools to check the style used in the issue node. Remove the style which causes it from your code.

Comment: It's not a custom navigation, and the issue only occurs on modern pages. I have so far gotten no where with Microsoft Support on this one :-(

When using f12 developer tools we are able to remove it by getting rid of the borders in the code. We aren't able to make this change on the standard seattle theme master page however

Comment: Currently, it is unsupported to customize the modern master page. refer to https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/solution-guidance/modern-experience-customizations-customize-pages.  You can contact Office 365 technical support via "https://support.office.com/en-us/article/contact-support-for-business-products-admin-help-32a17ca7-6fa0-4870-8a8d-e25ba4ccfd4b?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US#ID0EAADAAA=Get_fast_support_online!" Provide as much additional information as possible to describe your issue.